# A coin is tossed, coming up heads with probability $p$. What is the expected number of flips until there are $n$ heads total?

Tags: probability, negative-binomial

My thought process is: $X$ can only take on values greater than or equal to $n$. (Clearly, we cannot get $n$ heads in less than $n$ flips.) If $X=n$, that means every flip was a head, so this occurs with probability $p^n$. If $X=n+1$, this means there were $n$ heads and $1$ tail, and the tail can be at any one of the first $n$ spots. (It cannot be the $n+1$-th flip as then $X=n$.) So this occurs at probability $(1-p)p^n\binom{n}{1}$. By similar logic, $X=n+k$ with probability $(1-p)^kp^n\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. So we get $$\mathbb{E}(X) = p^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty (n+k)(1-p)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}.$$

Intuitively, I want to get the number $n/p$ but how to get this from my sum?

Comment: Recursively, letting $E_n$ be the desired answer, argue that we have $E_n=1+(1-p)E_n+pE_{n-1}$ then show that your guess satisfies that recursion and matches for $E_1$.

Comment: No...if you get $T$ then you have flipped once and you still need to get $n$ $H's$ so that second term should be $(1-p)(E_n+1)$.

Comment: The expected toss to get one head is $\frac{1}{p}$ (prove it). To get $n$ heads, you simply need to get one head, $n$ times so the expected toss to get $n$ heads is $\frac{n}{p}$

Answer (score 1):

Coming up heads with probability $p$ means that in $N\,$ flips we get $n=pN\,$ heads,
so $N=n/p$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$
(n+k)\binom{n+k-1}{k}
= \frac{(n+k)(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!k!} 
= \frac{(n+k)!}{(n-1)!k!}
= n\frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!}
=n\binom{n+k}{k},
$$

so letting $x = 1 - p$ we can write
$$
E(X) = n (1-x)^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k.
$$
By the ratio test, the series converges when $\lvert x\rvert < 1$.

But, using the fact that $\displaystyle\binom ab = \binom{a-1}{b-1} + \binom{a-1}b$,
if $n \geq 1$ we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k
&= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k && \binom{n+0}{0} x^0 = 1 \\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\binom{n+k-1}{k} + \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\right) x^k \\
&= \left( 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{k} x^k\right)
     + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{k-1} x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{k} x^k + \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{n+m}{m} x^{m+1}
&& k\to m+1\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{k} x^k + x\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k
&& m \to k\\
\end{align}

and therefore
$$
(1 - x) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{(n-1)+k}{k} x^k,
$$
so
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k
 = \frac{1}{1 - x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{(n-1)+k}{k} x^k. \tag1
$$

This suggest an inductive proof.

**Lemma**: If $n \geq 0$ and $\lvert x\rvert < 1$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{n+1}}.$$

Proof: For the base case $n = 0,$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k
 = \frac{1}{1 - x} = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{n+1}}.
$$

Now assume that for some $n = m \geq 0,$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{n+1}}.$$

Then by Equation $(1)$ and the inductive hypothesis,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{(m+1)+k}{k} x^k
 = \frac{1}{1 - x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m+k}{k} x^k
 = \frac{1}{1 - x} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{m+1}}
 = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{m+2}},
$$
proving the proposition for $n = m + 1$, which completes the inductive step
and proves the lemma. $\square$

Then we can conclude that
$$
E(X) = n (1-x)^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^k
= n (1-x)^n \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{n+1}} = \frac{n}{1-x}
$$
and therefore $E(X) = n/p.$

---

But I think a far easier method is to define random variables $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$
so that $Y_1$ is the number of flips up to and including the first head,
and for $k \geq 2$, $Y_k$ is the number of flips after the $(k-1)$th head,
up to and including the $k$th head.
Then
$$ X = Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_n, $$
so by the linearity of expectation,
$$ E(X) = E(Y_1) + E(Y_2) + \cdots + E(Y_n), $$
and since $E(Y_k) = 1/p$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$,
$$ E(X) = n\cdot \frac1p = \frac np.$$